# Alexa skill: EXCEEDED_MAX_REPROMPTS when delegating to get an AMAZON.Date

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I'm developing a skill using the node.js v2 sdk. In a certain point of the skill, I'm trying to get a date using the AMAZON.Date slot type like:

```
  return handlerInput.responseBuilder
    .addDelegateDirective(handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent)
    .getResponse();
```

The problem is that sometimes, not always, I get a EXCEEDED_MAX_REPROMPTS in this moment, I'm not even getting the Alexa prompt: "When do you want it?".

Why am I getting this error?

Thank you and best regards,
Ignacio

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and needed to [find out](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/75225/handling-exceeded-max-reprompts.html) that EXCEEDED_MAX_REPROMPTS can also mean that Alexa is not confident enough about your spoken utterance.

- In my case it was quite simple - I used the Amazon.YesIntent in my backend but forgot to add this intent to the model in developer console. So Alexa was not confident enough about my "Yes" which it was not expecting
- In your case I have seen a similar issue also about some numbers are recognized and others not: https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/72001/getting-exceeded-max-reprompts-when-user-says-cert.html  So maybe you should also ask your question there to get direct support of Amazon